# Rotating sprite to face vector in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a zombie gameObject in unity along with a tower gameObject.
I have tryed a bunch of things to get the enemy to face the location of a nested object inside the tower and nothing has worked.

I've already tried using Mathf.Acos to no effect.
The closest i got was using this code;
but it still obscures the intended direction slightly and i haven't found a pattern yet.

```
Vector2 direction = centralTower.transform.position + centralTower.transform.parent.transform.position - gameObject.transform.position;

transform.up = direction;
gameObject.transform.position += transform.up;
```

I know the first line looks like a mouthful but basically it can be simplified to this

direction = (TowerPosition + TowerChild(attakcingPoint)Position) - enemyPosition

BTW: central Tower variable refers to the attacking Point

I really don't have any idea what is happening and I've been researching angles for days now to no effect.

Comment: Did you try [LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) method? Something like `gameObject.LookAt(centralTower, Vector3.up);` ?

Comment: Is it possible to use the lookat method in a 2d enviroment as when i use it my transform values just flip out all over the place

Comment: I think but i didn't try yet. Try different value for the second parameter

Comment: @Procode238 Why are you adding two absolute positions together? Can you include more information about what you are trying to calculate when you say `TowerPosition + TowerChild(attakcingPoint)Position`? Are you sure you don't mean `direction = centralTower.transform.position - transform.position` so that the enemy points towards the centralTower's transform?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I have an object nested inside the tower position called attackingPoint. I would use the attackingPoint Position except it's position is relative to it's parent. So I added the tower position and the attackingPoint position to get the attackingPoint's position relative to the hierarchy

Comment: thanks ruzihm i looked it up and there seems to be a simple solution involving lookAt

Answer (score 1):

A [similar question](https://answers.unity.com/questions/585035/lookat-2d-equivalent-.html) provided the answer `transform.right = target.position - transform.position;`

Comment: not to be rude thank you for responding but isn't that technically what i'm doing here? The only problem is the nested objects positions are relative to their parents so to find that position relative to the in-game world you need to add the positions together. the rest is the same no.

Comment: From Asker's code, it looks like the front of the sprite is in its `up` direction, so it should be `transform.up = ...`